# OpenStack networksetup for Install using AutoPilot

Tags: networking, openstack

I am trying to install OpenStack using AutoPilot on a single VMware ESX. I have a very simple config.  Two vSwitches one Router.

The online instructions say:
"In vSphere, make at least a full /24 subnet available for this deployment."

So I have made 192.168.1.x available on one side of the router and my internal lab network available on the other side of the router.  From the lab network I cannot ping the 192.168.1.x network but I can ping externally from the 192.186.1.x.

I have imported/deployed  the three cloudnode vm's (not yet powered) and the openstack_autopilot VM all on the 192.168.1.x subnet.  Is this where they belong?
I have powered up the openstack_autopilot VM anwsered the questions and all went well.
Not it wants be to bring it up in a browser https://IP/MAAS/#/node  but I do not have browser access to the subnet .... meaning a machine on the subnet does not have a browser available.
So this mean I need to figure out how get a machine external to the subnet with a browser to access the 198.168.1.x subnet.  WHat is generally done here?

Answer (score 0):

First - I configured a Windows server on the private subnet at 192.168.1.254 and used it to open the MASS URL.  I found that the MAAS URL that is references on the AutoPilot Server on 192.168.1.2 after running autopilot-config did not work.  Instead I needed to use http://192.168.1.2:5240/MAAS.  that worked.  I got the URL from running sudo dpkg-reconfigure maas-region-controller (I believe that's what it was).